# IEの「イントラネット サイトを互換表示で表示する」について

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

IEの「イントラネット サイトを互換表示で表示する」について教えてください。

今回作成したアプリをIE11で開こうとすると、「イントラネット サイトを互換表示で表示する」の設定のせいだと思われるのですが、IE7のモードで表示されてレイアウトが乱れてしまいます。
よって試しに「イントラネット サイトを互換表示で表示する」のチェックを外してみると、期待しているレイアウトになりました。

そこで X-UA-Compatible を指定したところ、F12開発者ツールでモードが変更されたことは確認しました。しかしながらレイアウトが乱れたままでした。
コンソールを見ると 、[イントラネット サイトを互換表示で表示する] がオンであるため、互換表示で実行中です、というログが出ています。

X-UA-Compatible を指定することで互換表示の解除ができると思っていたのですが（実際にモードは変更されています）、この現象の意味が理解できないです。

何か単純な勘違いをしていそうですが、お分かりの方お教えください。

Comment: サーバはIISを使っていますか? 「X-UA-Compatible を指定」はページ内のHTMLで行いましたか?

Comment: コメントをありがとうございます。サーバーは IBM HTTP Serverになります。「X-UA-Compatible」はサーバーサイドのコードで、ヘッダに書き込んでいます。

Comment: この記事 [信頼済みサイトに登録していても、"イントラネットサイトを互換表示で表示する" の設定が有効な場合には、互換表示となる場合があります](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2904443) の最後の方の書かれた状況が関係しているのかもしれません。あとはこの記事が何か参考になるかも。[IEの持つ互換性機能の全て - DOCTYPEスイッチ/X-UA-Compatible/互換表示](http://furoshiki.hatenadiary.jp/entry/ie_documentmode)

Comment: 情報をありがとうございます。X-UA-Compatible を指定していて、実際にモードは変わるのですが、上にも書きましたように [イントラネット サイトを互換表示で表示する] がオンであるため、互換表示で実行中です、というログが出てしまいます。その影響であると思うのですが、使用しているライブラリが IE7 対応に関連する CSS を当ててきて、レイアウトが乱れるという結果になっております。